# All my links showing just home page, htaccess issue

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I am unable to visit any page, all menu link redirect me to the same home page.
Here is my htacess file, really didn't understand after a lot of googling even.
Kind Regards

```
 Options +FollowSymLinks
 RewriteEngine On
 RewriteBase /
 #Redirect 301 /?action=main.cancel_newsletter http://www.mysite.us/Cancel

 RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^action=main.cancel\_newsletter$
 RewriteRule ^/*$ http://www.mysite.us/Cancel? [L,R=301]

 RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^action=main.market\_news$
 RewriteRule ^/*$ http://www.mysite.us/News? [L,R=301]

 RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^action=main.profiled\_companies$
 RewriteRule ^/*$ http://www.mysite.us/ProfiledCompanies? [L,R=301]

 RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^action=main.adregister$
 RewriteRule ^/*$ http://www.mysite.us/Register? [L,R=301]

 RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^action=main.register$
 RewriteRule ^/*$ http://www.mysite.us/Register? [L,R=301]


RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule .* /index.php [L]

<IfModule mod_security.c>

SecFilterEngine Off

SecFilterScanPOST Off

</IfModule>
```

Comment: Can you provide us the links URL your are clicking on ?

Comment: If you move your `.htaccess` away can you navigate then?

Comment: i transferred my site to new server, but the issue is same,
the URL is http://www.stockprofiler.us

Comment: anubhava when i rename or delete .htaccess file, all pages says not found